# find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sin(n^2)}{n} $?

Tags: real-analysis

Find $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sin(n^2)}{n}.$$

My attempt :$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sin(n^2)}{n} =
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sin(n^2)}{n^2} \cdot n=  \infty$$

since  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sin(n^2)}{n^2}=1.$

Is this correct?

Any hints/solutions

thank u

Comment: Should these limits be going to $0$?

Comment: Is the limit going to zero or infinity? The answer  is incorrect either way, since the ratio limit is for $n \to 0$ but then you are multiplying with $n$ which you assume is going to infinity.

Comment: @joe   $\infty$...

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  infinity

Comment: @jasmine Ok. Then, the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin n^2}{n^2}$ is *not equal to one*. That applies when $n$ approaches zero. So you will have to use some other approach. In particular, squeeze the given function using the fact that $-1 \leq \sin n^2 \leq 1$

Comment: @jasmine I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be going to zero. Notably, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(n^2)}{n^2} = 0$, not $1$ as written above. However, $\lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(n^2)}{n^2} = 1$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг    now my doubt is that  $ lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \frac {sin n^2}{n^2}= 1$ as  joe  as mention in comment ?    why  we not used  sequeeze  theorem on this

Comment: @jasmine, you can prove it using L'Hopital's Theorem on $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be $0$ since the numerator will take values between $-1$ and $1$ while the denominator tends to infinity.
Also, the limit you mentioned is $0$ and not $1$ by similar reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

$|\frac{\sin(n^2)}{n}|\leq \frac1n,$ so it goes to $0$.